# Selecting a previous div with a class name from a onclick event and adding to it's class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there are tons of posts out here about this but I have yet to find anything that works. I think because how deep my button is nested versus the postion of the div I am trying to effect.

Most of this is generated dynamically so I can't target IDs but I can target classes.

I have tried a number of approaches. Including:

```
$('div.hold:first').addClass('skinSelected');

AND

$(this).parent.parent.parent.prev('.hold').addClass('skinSelected')

AND

$(this).parent.prev('.hold').addClass('skinSelected')
```

This does the job to the first div with class hold but I have numerous divs with class "hold"

Here's my HTML:

```
<li>
<a>...</a>
<div style="display:none" class"hold">current selection</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <span>....</span>
        <div>....</div>
        <div>
            <h3>...</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="passSkinID()">select</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function passSkinID() {
    $('div.skinSelected').removeClass('skinSelected');
    $(this).prevAll('.hold:first').addClass('skinSelected')
}
</script>
```

And here is my css

```
<style>
    .skinSelected {
    background-size:cover; 
    width:100%; 
    background:#2d67a3; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block !important;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use `$(this)` as it reffers to the jQuery's *window* object. You should pass `this` on click, and then wrap it into jquery object.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="passSkinID(this)">select</a>
```

Script:

```
function passSkinID(el) {
    $('div.skinSelected').removeClass('skinSelected');
    // use passed element instead of $(this):
    $(el).closest('li').find('.hold').addClass('skinSelected');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mfrtz2f/)

---

I would however do it this way:

```
<a href="#" class="my-btn btn btn-primary" >select</a>
```

Script:

```
$('.my-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.skinSelected').removeClass('skinSelected');
    $(this).closest('li').find('.hold').addClass('skinSelected');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8zjdkzz/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the event is triggered on a child of a `<li>` tag that also contains the elements you want to manipulate, you have to travel up the DOM to that parent with `closest()` then find all children that have the required class:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.hold').addClass('skinSelected')
```

This will only work if between `<li>` and the link you don't have other `<li>`'s, and if the other `.hold` elements that you don't want to add the class to are outside this particular `<li>` tree. I imagine that your DOM structure is like this:

```
<li>
<a>...</a>
<div style="display:none" class"hold">current selection</div>
<div>
    <div>
        ...
        <div>
            ...
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="passSkinID()">select</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</li>   

<li>
<a>...</a>
<div style="display:none" class"hold">current selection</div>
<div>
    <div>
        ...
        <div>
            ...
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="passSkinID()">select</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</li>   
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first you need and equl in you div elemnt with class "hold"

You can do this as i have done in this jsBin http://jsbin.com/lujekojami/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I hope it helps :)